# Create dynamic page content from custom Wordpress plugin page

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I would like to create a custom Wordpress page from a plugin displaying content that is not from Wordpress with 2 get parameters and apply rewriting rules on it.

Let's say I have a file called test.php. I would like with 2 get parameters to display content using the URL:

example.com/param1/param2/

I'm good on the plugin side (Admin, etc...) but have no clue about custom page. At the moment I have this code in my test.php file but I'm really not sure if that's the right way to do:

```
include('../../../wp-load.php');
include('myplugin.php');

global $myclass, $wpdb;

echo $myclass->get_setting('test');
```

Or would I need to check query vars parameters passed in URL and modify content accordingly?

I tried some stackoverflow answers without success so if you could hint me up on this. Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a page for this purpose, which you can filter its content later UNLESS you are working other way.
2. Add the page ID to the rewrite rule init function:

   ```
   add_action('init', function() {

       $page = get_post( 2 ); // replace 2 with page ID

       add_rewrite_rule(
           '([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$',
           'index.php?pagename=' . $page->post_name . '&my_param_1=$matches[1]&my_param_2=$matches[2]',
           'top'
       );

   });
   ```
3. Append the query variables to the main query:

   ```
   add_filter('query_vars', function($vars) {
       $vars[] = "my_param_1";
       $vars[] = "my_param_2";
       return $vars;
   });
   ```

You should be done now and you need to flush the rewrite rules with either `flush_rewrite_rules()` hooked to `init` or `wp`, or go to Settings > Permalinks and hit the save button in the bottom.

Now a test > `http://example.com/john/smith/` :

```
// first param
echo var_dump( get_query_var( 'my_param_1' ) ); // john

// second param
echo var_dump( get_query_var( 'my_param_2' ) ); // smith
```

I hope that works for you as it did in my local installation.

Edit: It would be much better if you make the parameters go after the page name like `$page->post_name . '/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$'` so you get `/sample-page/john/smith/` This way you won't make any conflicts to existing contents and WordPress will serve the existing content initially before passing to your plugin OR add a unique prefix before the first param slug. Just a thought so.

Comment: Create a page for this purpose? You mean in admin pages? If yes do you think it can be done without? Thanks for your precious help!!

Comment: No, a front-end page. Pages > Add New or with `wp_insert_post()` in your plugin https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/

Comment: It would be better to work with a page so you benefit from the page template. After that you use `add_filter('the_content' ...)` to set the content for that page. Or even better, through a custom shortcode, I recommend this one.

Comment: Yes but what if I wanna display a page without any content? Just the 2 get variables? Thanks a lot for your help!!

Comment: No worries. You mean like printing the variables in the page content?

Comment: On the new page, I would like to use curl function and display total new page, where second parameter would a url. Get content of the URL with curl and display it on custom page.

Comment: Ok so create a shortcode adding this code to your plugin http://pastebin.com/7PBtyc7M then add it as your page content `[wpse226928-page-content]`. In the shortcode coding you can work with `file_get_contents` or `curl` to get the external contents, that's another topic.

Comment: So the shortcode will display the content of curl request right? My friend you are the one! I owe you big time!

Comment: Can you just clarify where to use the shortcode without creating new page/post? In the init hook action?

Comment: Emilie, if you don't create the page, you wouldn't be able to display the content. The shortcode code from the paste should be added along your plugin code if that is what you meant. Sorry if I am missing your point.

Comment: My point is to maybe display the content fetched from curl request in init hook action and then die? So only the curl content will be displayed and not WP content?

Comment: Ah. now I get it. that is like making your own API urls.. `add_action('wp', function() { echo do_shortcode('[wpse226928-page-content]'); exit; });`..

Comment: Ahhhh perfect!!!! Thanks a lot. You ended 2 days of struggle!!!

Comment: Awesome!! if you have told so from the beginning, we wouldn't be worried about the pages. a custom page is totally not necessary for this, I could edit the answer if you want.

Comment: No all good. You the one!